# Laptop cooling fan stops suddenly

Tags: fan

I'm having this problem for a long time. The cooling solution (single fan for CPU and GPU) on my LG 590 (5700) laptop, suddenly stops to work and don't start again causing overheat and consequential system shutdown to prevent damage.

How can I solve this?

[I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 but the laptop was originally designed to run Windows.]

---

Thanks for your replies.

- The fan works normal on Windows. It doesn't stop cooling even under heavy load such as games or full hd videos. As the processing temperature increases, the rotation rises too. In Ubuntu it happens in reverse; when under heavy load it just stops spinning.
- I always use the latest stable driver version of graphics card.
- I have fancontrol installed because of this post: "How to control fan speed?". Even tried to follow the tutorial of the final answer but got stuck after "sudo pwmconfig", where it shows this: "There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed".

Comment: If you run windows with the current driver - does the cooler also stop? Just want to be sure, maybe this is not an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: do you have any fan management software installed? fancontrol maybe?

Comment: So Im not alone...

Comment: Before pwmconfig can work, you need to execute `sudo sensors-detect` which will detect sensors and add the kernel modules. The program sensors-detect can be found in the package lm-sensors.

Comment: Do you have a directory /sys/class/hwmon? if so, what is its content?

Comment: what would `find /sys/class/hwmon -follow -maxdepth 3` show you. This directory hwmon often stores the info and allows the stearing of them cpu-temperature and fan-satus

Answer (score 1):

It worth mentioning that the reporter has also fired a bug for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1125052

So it will be also tracked there...